# Access attributes from XML in shell

Tags: xslt, shell, debian, widget

I'm trying to parse out values from a Widget [config.xml](http://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/widgets/#configuration-document) using shell. I do want to use sed for this task. If there is something that [sucks less](http://suckless.org/) than xsltproc, I'd love to know.

In this example I am after the **id** attribute value from the `config.xml` below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://example.org/exampleWidget" version="2.0 Beta" height="200" width="200">
<name short="123">Foo Widget</name>
</widget>
```

I wish it was as simple as [Jquery's attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr): `var id = $("widget").attr("id");`

Currently this shell code utilising `xsltproc` fails:

```
snag () {
TMP=$(tempfile)
cat << EOF > $TMP
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template>
<xsl:value-of select="$1"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF

echo $(xsltproc $TMP config.xml)
rm -f $TMP
}

ID=$(snag "widget/@id")

if test "$ID" = "http://example.org/exampleWidget"
then
    echo Mission accomplished.
else
    echo "<$ID> is wrong."
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLStarlet (http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is a nice command line tools that supports such queries:

xmlstarlet sel -N w=namespace -T -t -m "/w:widget/@id" -v . -n config.xml

Comment: Have you tried this command? It doesn't work for me on 1.0.1.

Comment: I forgot the widget namespace in the first try. You have to replace 'namespace' with the value from your xml, Stackoverflow won't let new users paste more than one url.

Comment: How extraordinary, it works. 

`hendry@x61 shell$ xmlstarlet sel -N w="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" -T -t -m "/w:widget/@id" -v . -n config.xml
http://webvm.net/widgets/123`

However there is an aboniation of switches there. Insane!!

Answer (score 0):

template match="widget"

select value-of="@id"

Answer (score 0):

<xsl:template xmlns:wgt="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" match="/wgt:widget">
<xsl:select value-of="@id" />
</xsl:template>

Comment: hendry@x61 shell$ sh foo.sh 
 /tmp/file3jey7M:3: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute value-of
 <xsl:select value-of select="@id" />
       ^
 /tmp/file3jey7M:3: parser error : attributes construct error
 <xsl:select value-of select="@id" />
       ^
 /tmp/file3jey7M:3: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag select line 3
 <xsl:select value-of select="@id" />
       ^
 cannot parse /tmp/file3jey7M

Answer (score 0):

You don't need XSLT if you're not doing a transform.
If you only need to grab a value use XPath.

There's an xpath program that comes with Perl's XML::XPath module.

From the shell: 
ID=$(xpath config.xml 'string(/widget/@id)' )

( The string() function is to get only the value of the id.

/widget/@id by itself returns  "id=value"  )

If you only need to produce some other output depending on the value, you could
do it all in xslt. There are also other XPath implementations available from
other scripting languages: I've used Java's XPath from both rhino and Jython. 
There's also XQuery from the command line with Saxon.

Comment: Xpath looks really heavy compared to `xmlstarlet`.